# Failed to build gevent

Tags: python, gcc, installation, pip, gevent

When trying to install gevent on Windows using

```
pip install gevent-websocket
```

It fails to build wheel for gevent..

```
  In file included from deps\libuv\src\win/internal.h:29,
                   from deps\libuv\src\fs-poll.c:26:
  deps\libuv\src\win/winapi.h:4730:16: error: redefinition of 'struct _TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS'
   4730 | typedef struct _TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS {
        |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/ws2tcpip.h:265,
                   from C:\Users\crj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c9ig6g3l\gevent_62610c4d6c1a41b7a182996b943d31fd\deps\libuv\include/uv/win.h:48,
                   from C:\Users\crj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c9ig6g3l\gevent_62610c4d6c1a41b7a182996b943d31fd\deps\libuv\include/uv.h:64,
                   from deps\libuv\src\fs-poll.c:22:
  C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/mstcpip.h:163:16: note: originally defined here
    163 | typedef struct _TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS {
        |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from deps\libuv\src\win/internal.h:29,
                   from deps\libuv\src\fs-poll.c:26:
  deps\libuv\src\win/winapi.h:4733:3: error: conflicting types for 'TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS'; have 'struct _TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS'
   4733 | } TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS, *PTCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS;
        |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/ws2tcpip.h:265,
                   from C:\Users\crj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c9ig6g3l\gevent_62610c4d6c1a41b7a182996b943d31fd\deps\libuv\include/uv/win.h:48,
                   from C:\Users\crj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c9ig6g3l\gevent_62610c4d6c1a41b7a182996b943d31fd\deps\libuv\include/uv.h:64,
                   from deps\libuv\src\fs-poll.c:22:
  C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/mstcpip.h:166:3: note: previous declaration of 'TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS' with type 'TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS'
    166 | } TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS, *PTCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS;
        |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from deps\libuv\src\win/internal.h:29,
                   from deps\libuv\src\fs-poll.c:26:
  deps\libuv\src\win/winapi.h:4733:32: error: conflicting types for 'PTCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS'; have 'struct _TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS *'
   4733 | } TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS, *PTCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS;
        |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/ws2tcpip.h:265,
                   from C:\Users\crj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c9ig6g3l\gevent_62610c4d6c1a41b7a182996b943d31fd\deps\libuv\include/uv/win.h:48,
                   from C:\Users\crj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c9ig6g3l\gevent_62610c4d6c1a41b7a182996b943d31fd\deps\libuv\include/uv.h:64,
                   from deps\libuv\src\fs-poll.c:22:
  C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/mstcpip.h:166:32: note: previous declaration of 'PTCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS' with type 'PTCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS' {aka 'struct _TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS *'}
    166 | } TCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS, *PTCP_INITIAL_RTO_PARAMETERS;
        |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  error: command 'C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
Failed to build gevent
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried searching for this problem, and tried the solutions sited, but it still doesn't work for me. Does anyone know how to properly install gevent.

Comment: What is your python version? gevent has a lot of [whl files available](https://pypi.org/project/gevent/#files), so I am wondering why it tries to compile from source

Comment: @FlyingTeller I'm using python 3.9